# Connected Mode on SonarLint v2.0 on IntelliJ not working?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

SonarLint v2.0 for IntelliJ is out now, and has this "connect to sonar server" feature, but even so, it seems it isn't in sync with my server rules.

http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/#Connected

Is it working for someone?
I'm I missing a step?
Or could it be a bug?

Thanks!

IntelliJ Idea Version: 2016.1
SonarLint Version: 2.0.1
SonarQube Version: 5.4

Comment: Check if you are using any third party analzyers, like PMD or FindBug. SonarLint doesn't support them. 
More info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarlint/4mhnQ4zFsvM/w3ZeO_I9AgAJ)

Comment: That is probably it. Seems that the issues that are not found in idea are old PMD rules. I will try to update them, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarLint, as of now, won't work with third party analyzers like PMD or FindBug, if you are using those, they will simple be ignored.

You can update your rules in SonarQube Server to only use rules defined in the SonarQube repository, most of them have an equivalent version.

Comment: But what to do with custom checks and custom rules developed with the checkstyle and PMD APIs?

Answer (score -2):

Please check SonarLint console for details and open a thread on SonarLint Google group so that we can investigate.