# SonarLint can't find Java "Code Smell" in connected mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint, code-inspection

I try to use the [SonarLint plugin](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/) for IntelliJ in connected mode.

However, it seems that the remote rules work for JavaScript files, but not for Java files.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the example above, even a simple rule as: "Line is longer than 120 characters" is **found** by the remove SonarQube server, but **not found** by the SonarLint IntelliJ plugin.

Do you have any idea why not all of the rules are in sync?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connected Mode on SonarLint v2.0 on IntelliJ not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803897/connected-mode-on-sonarlint-v2-0-on-intellij-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

What is the key of the rule? It is my understanding that SonarLint only supports the SonarSource analyzer (rules with prefix `squid`).

Also see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/EmXINryXdos

> SonarLint will only execute SonarSource
>   analyzers. PMD/Findbugs/Checkstyle engines are not supported in
>   SonarLint.